# Python - Can't run multiple queries in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-itertools

I've a script that receives multiple connections (it can be MySQL, MSSQL, etc.) and execute some queries using Python. I am making some achievements by making my process to run those queries in parallel. For that I receive a dataframe and based on column values I run those queries. For that I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
import util
import os
from itertools import product

df = pd.read_excel("myFile.xlsx", sheet_name = 'data')

conn, engine = #connections

def work(query):
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.rowcount
    except SyntaxError as e:
        result = -999
    return result

def run(df):
    results = []
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(os.cpu_count())
    total_rows = pool.starmap(work, product(df["queries"]), chunksize=1)
    results.append(total_rows)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    run(df)
```

But when I run my code I am getting the following error:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dev.py", line 42, in <module>
    run(df)
  File "dev.py", line 34, in run
    total_rows = pool.starmap(work, product(df["dsc_test_query"]), chunksize=1)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 372, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Anyone knows the best option to run a queries list in parallel?

Thanks!

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: done, I've updated the question with more details from the error

Comment: to you question - "Anyone knows the best option to run a queries list in parallel?", I would recommend using aiohttp

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
result = cursor.rowcount
```

is probably causing the error. The function 'work' is throwing the Attribute
error, which you are observing. If i replace the work function with something like

```
def work(url):
    raise Exception("some exception")
    result = -999
    return result
```

I can  observer similar behaviour. Most likely you are processing the `result` in something that expects a string.